# Converting a file in C# into byte array before parsing it into Java

Tags: java, c#, arrays, json, byte

Forgive if this question is incredibly poorly phrased, but I'll do my best to explain what is (to me) a rather complex situation. I am fully aware that I am in way over my head here, experience wise, but I am hoping one of you can help me.

I come to you brighter minds with this, because I am in a complete rut and there appears to be no light at the end of the tunnel.

I have a file I wish converted with `C#` to a `byte` array, because the `byte` array will be sent as an argument into a `Java` method.

So I thought:

```
byte[] a = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePathHere);
```

Now, this works, and all is peaceful in the world. But the problem arises when i try to send `a` into my `Java` method.

The error it throws me when i try to send this to my `Java` file by means of `JSON` is:

> org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Numeric value (181) out of
>   range of Java byte

Now, after some (in vain) Googling, I came to the conclusion that `C#` thinks its being helpful by converting the file into a `byte` array that contains items with value between `0` and `255`.

While `Java` is expecting to get as an argument for my method is a `byte` array with values reaching from `-128` to `128`.

In an ideal world, I would love it if any of you knew how to convert my file `C#` into a `byte` array with values reaching from `-128` to `128`.

However, if this is in fact impossible, I would also be open to, in `Java`, converting my `byte` array with value between `0` and `255` to a more desired `-128` to `128` format.

Is what I describe impossible, or does someone know how this can be done?

I deeply appreciate any help anyone can provide. The more detailed and noob-friendly, the better!

Comment: you can see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18428891/java-code-negative-byte-in-byte-array-to-c-sharp

Comment: Would iterating over the c# byte array and converting the byte at that position to a signed int help?  I'm not familiar with doing this, but came across this msdn article: [BitConverter.ToInt32 Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint32(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: nevermind, looks like mo.ashfaq took care of it.

Comment: and also for reading of the file you can see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23129598/how-to-read-signed-bytes-from-a-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting types in C# is relatively trivial:

```
File.ReadAllBytes(filePathHere).Select(b=>(sbyte)b).ToArray();
```

As a side note, files are *supposed* to be made of unsigned bytes, so there's no need for sarcasm ("C# thinks its being helpful"). It's just that Java doesn't have proper data types to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

This is because Java works with signed numeric primitives only, while c# `byte`s are unsigned 8 bit integers.

How to solve in the Java side:

- You can read it in a integer/short array and then force cast to a byte array, byte by byte.
- If you need to work with numbers in the interval [0-255], you **should** use a integer or short array.

How to solve in C# side:

- use a `sbyte` ([signed byte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d86he86x.aspx)) array [-128 to 127].